# Gson error JellyBean

Tags: android, eclipse, gson, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have an Android app which uses the Gson jar in the referenced libraries. I'm currently using version 2.2.4 and I have 2 phones to test it.

On a Samsung Galaxy S Advance 2.3.6 all works perfectly while on an LG Nexus 4 4.2.2 I got the error

```
The JAR gson-2.4.4 has no source attachment.
```

and in the Log file

```
java.Lang.StackoverflowError
```

Of course I correctly imported the needed libraries otherwise it wouldn't have worked on Android 2.3.6.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks

This is the Stack:

```
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-92
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038): java.lang.StackOverflowError
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at               com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:355)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:356)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:118)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:356)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:118)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:356)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:118)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:356)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
05-28 14:58:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
```

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace that's causing the overflow?

Comment: Have you written any custom parsing for GSON? If so can you post this code. It looks like you have gotten into an infinite loop, this is easy to do with GSON.

Comment: But why it works with Android 2.3.6???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a bug related to changes made in newer Android versions. Without seeing the class you are trying to serialize it's hard to pin point the problem. This [thread](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=440) discusses the issue you're having and may point you in the right direction. If you're unable to locate the problem it sounds like reverting Gson to 1.7.1 will work.

Comment: Ehi man you are great! This is working! By the way, it's really absurd how compatibility is handled in Android, especially for the 2.* versions...